# Is there any evidence that this character survived the helicopter crash in X-Men: Apocalypse?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse, marvel

In X-Men Apocalypse, is there any evidence that:

> Angel/Archangel

survived the helicopter explosion?

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Angel_(Earth-TRN414)) it's clear that;

> "*...Although they succeeded in causing the plane to crash, Angel was
>   trapped on the plane while Nightcrawler teleported Xavier and his
>   allies away from the crash. **Angel was killed in the crash.** Apocalypse
>   called his fallen Horseman "useless" when he found Angel's lifeless
>   body in the wreckage...*

Edit:

Because of the answer of @Valorum I decided to dig down that question.

As I understand from rewatching the movie, it looks like he's dead. So thinks Apocalypse, that even with his imbued power, Angel was not able to safe himself.

As [Moviepilot.com](https://moviepilot.com/posts/3929765) wrote:

> *... it remains unclear whether or not Angel even survived the final battle.*

They also hope, he survived, so he would get more development in future movie(s). Or as *Comicbook.com* puts it:

> *Archangel may have died [...], but it's a little easier to write that one off and let him survive. [...] but that was post-Apocalypse's manipulation and upgrading of him. With Apocalypse's armored upgrades, and Angel's healing factor in the comics, there's a good chance he made it out of that seemingly devastating situation.*

This tells me, that it's likely, that he survived the crash, if they keep it closer to the comic books, specially because of the healing powers as well as (see further down -Screenrant) the possibility to protect himself.

And then there is *Busted.com*, and they state, that:

> *[...] To be fair, with his Apocalypse-given metal wings, it's possible Angel survived to see another day. But, if his death is, in fact, real, then it's a shame. He might have been fighting for the wrong side, but he was still pretty cool.*

*DenOfGeek.com*:

> The fate of [...] Angel is a bit less obvious. He was last seen burried under some rubble during the final battle, and an unimpressed Apocalypse just left him there. Is he dead? It’s hard to tell, which means he could show up in another movie if the writers can find a good enough reason.

And finally *Screenrant.com*:

> *[...] Archangel’s death is somewhat ambiguous. He is trapped inside the stolen military plane [...] and is there to take the full brunt of the plane’s crash landing and explosion [...] Though it seems like that kind of crash would blow him to pieces, Angel is shown lying in the rubble afterwards, unmoving and covered in blood, with Apocalypse deriding him as “useless.” That’s the last time Archangel is shown in the movie, implying that he was killed, but there’s a possibility that he managed to shield himself from the worst of the explosion with his metal wings and could perhaps return in a future sequel.*

So, if we sum that up, all those sources tend to think, or prefer, that he survived somehow. Might that be because of his healing powers in the comic books, his skills of protecting himself, the power given by Apocalypse which make him a better survivor in generall, or just plain luck. However, it is not clear in the movie. From what we see in that movie alone, without the consultation of the comic books, it is likely he did not survive. He still could have, with the powers of Apocalypse.

Therefore my 'new' answer based on the sources above is - no, there is no clear evidence, he survived, but there is also no clear evidence he died.

Because of the '2 links limit' I have, I'll post the links as answers...

Comment: Anyone reading the question will already be prepared for spoilers. The tag is unnecessary.

Comment: Is a fan-written wiki a good source of info? On what are they basing this assertion? In the film all we see is his face, covered in minor lacerations. There's too much heat-haze to determine if he's breathing.

Comment: [Comicbook.com](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2016/05/26/who-dies-in-x-men-apocalypse-/)   [Busted.com](https://www.bustle.com/articles/163323-who-dies-in-x-men-apocalypse-the-mutants-lose-one-of-their-own)

[Screenrant.com](http://screenrant.com/x-men-apocalypse-movie-spoilers-reveals/?view=all)   [DenOfGeek.com](http://www.denofgeek.com/uk/movies/x-men-apocalypse/40735/x-men-apocalypse-where-does-it-leave-the-x-men-universe)

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the links you've provided that suggest that any of the sources have done any more research than simply looking at the film and seeing his body on screen. There are no interview quotes and no behind-the-scenes info in evidence.

Comment: That's the way I understood the question. I thought it's about the movie itself. How it's depicted. I'm pretty sure that in an interview with the producers, they would not say if he survived, if there's a chance, that they're thinking of giving him a surprising revival in an upcoming movie...

Comment: The problem here is that your answer boils down to what a bunch of people **with no connection to the movie** think about what they saw.